# No me agrupa los datos repetidos

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo un trabajo para mi instituto pero no me quiere agrupar los datos necesito ayuda por favor,alguna solucion please

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT to_char(e.numrun_emp,'999g999g999')||'-'||e.dvrun_emp "RUN EMPLEADO"

,(e.pnombre_emp ||' '||e.snombre_emp||' '||e.appaterno_emp||' '||e.apmaterno_emp) "NOMBRE EMPLEADO"

,TO_CHAR(e.SUELDO_base,'$999G999G999') "SUELDO BASE"

,ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,e.fecha_contrato)/12) "AÑOS TRABAJADOS"

,count(a.fecha_ini_arriendo) "TOTAL ARRIENDO ANUAL"

FROM empleado e join camion c on(e.numrun_emp=c.numrun_Emp)

join arriendo_camion a on (a.nro_patente=c.nro_patente)

where a.fecha_ini_arriendo between '01/09/19' and '27/09/19'

GROUP BY e.fecha_contrato,e.numrun_emp,e.dvrun_emp,e.pnombre_emp,e.snombre_emp,e.appaterno_emp,e.apmaterno_emp,e.SUELDO_base,a.fecha_ini_arriendo,a.fecha_devolucion

order by 2;
```

Comment: Intenta agrupar por los mismos valores que usaste en el SELECT, incluyendo las palabras reservadas, no por los campos literales. Así: GROUP BY TO_CHAR(e.numrun_emp,'999g999g999')||'-'||e.dvrun_emp .... omitiendo los ALIAS claro.

Comment: El motor de base de datos no es Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en la forma de ordenar los resultados. Siempre es importante ordenar según cómo se está seleccionando.

Ejemplo:

Si se desea concatenar o modificar el resultado que se va a mostrar cómo columna, es necesario agrupar según el mismo criterio.

```
to_char(e.numrun_emp,'999g999g999')||'-'||e.dvrun_emp
```

Ya que no es lo mismo agrupar `e.numrun_emp` y `e.dvrun_emp` por separado que juntos según como se pretende en la consulta.

Modificando la consulta agrupando según los criterios de selección quedaría como sigue:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(e.numrun_emp, '999g999g999') || '-' || e.dvrun_emp "RUN EMPLEADO",
       (e.pnombre_emp || ' ' || e.snombre_emp || ' ' 
                      || e.appaterno_emp || ' ' || e.apmaterno_emp) "NOMBRE EMPLEADO",
       TO_CHAR(e.SUELDO_base, '$999G999G999') "SUELDO BASE",
       ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, e.fecha_contrato) / 12) "AÑOS TRABAJADOS",
       COUNT(a.fecha_ini_arriendo) "TOTAL ARRIENDO ANUAL"
  FROM empleado e
  JOIN camion c ON (e.numrun_emp = c.numrun_Emp)
  JOIN arriendo_camion a ON (a.nro_patente = c.nro_patente)
 WHERE a.fecha_ini_arriendo BETWEEN '01/09/19' AND '27/09/19'
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(e.numrun_emp, '999g999g999') || '-' || e.dvrun_emp,
          (e.pnombre_emp || ' ' || e.snombre_emp || ' ' || e.appaterno_emp || ' ' || e.apmaterno_emp),
          TO_CHAR(e.SUELDO_base, '$999G999G999'),
          ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, e.fecha_contrato) / 12)
 order by 2;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio